# Google Calendar API - Modifying all following instances (update self attendee response status )

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have a recurring calendar event with multiple attendees. I want to update my own **responseStatus** for this event. I know how to update it for the particular event or all events in the recurring sequence however, it's not clear for me how to do that for the part of the sequence ("all following" instances option in the Google calendar). I followed this guide:
https://developers.google.com/calendar/recurringevents#modifying_all_following_instances

In the guide above we terminate the existing sequence and create a new one with updated data. How can I do that at an event where the creator (host) is another person, not me? I've tried the mentioned approach and as a result, I've created a new recurring event where I was a host with attendees listed in the source event. So how can I update my **responseStatus** for the all following instances at the event where I'm a regular attendee, not the host?

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)